# SFTP get throws errors (curl not working either)

Tags: ssh, cron, sftp

I am connecting to an SFTP connection via the terminal. I want to download a file.

If I go to the folder, I can list the contents:

```
ls
```

I can clearly see the file; let's call it "my_file.csv".

If I try this code:

```
sftp get my_file.csv
```

I get this error:

```
Connecting to get...
ssh: Could not resolve hostname get: Name or service not known
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

I can view the file with "less my_file.csv". It is clearly there and accessible, but I cannot download it with any combination of sftp get that I try (I have tried lots of options). I've also tried using curl but no luck.

If I type SFTP, I do get options:

```
usage: sftp [-1Cv] [-B buffer_size] [-b batchfile] [-F ssh_config]
            [-o ssh_option] [-P sftp_server_path] [-R num_requests]
            [-S program] [-s subsystem | sftp_server] host
       sftp [user@]host[:file ...]
       sftp [user@]host[:dir[/]]
       sftp -b batchfile [user@]host
```

Any help is appreciated! I am setting this up to download the file on a schedule ultimately (e.g., every hour).

Comment: As @emk2203 explains, `sftp` does not accept commands itself but opens an interactive dialog where (after authentication) you can use commands like `get` and `put`. However, using this in a script file is tricky. You will need to wrap the whole `sftp` dialog in an `expect` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sftp` wants the host as the first argument. So, if you form the argument like so:

`sftp user@host:my_file.csv`, it should work. With your command, `sftp` wrongly assumes that the hostname is `get`.

You can also add a path if you want to access other than the default for the `sftp` command on the server: `sftp user@host:/path/to/my_file.csv`.

`sftp` is more suited to interactive usage. For your purpose, as pointed out by @Jos, `scp` would be a better fit.

Comment: This is helping, but if I specify a local path I keep getting "Couldn't open local file for writing: No such file or directory". Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you confuse `sftp` with `scp`.

Comment: Yeah, but man SCP just refuses to copy the file locally. Insists there is no such file or directory even though it is there with full privileges. Frustrating as hell.

Comment: Nevermind, holy christ that was annoying. I was connected to the remote server trying to run scp to initiate a remote to local file copy. You have to run the ```scp``` command from a regular terminal logged into the local machine (not while logged into the remote machine). Live and learn! Thanks guys!

Comment: Not necessarily. In fact, I run `scp` often on the remote machine because I know the local paths, but need to see them on the remote machine. `ssh` into remote, then `scp /path/to/file homemachine.lan:/target/path` definitely works. It's like playing an indirect shot.